# Entity Framework Change Tracker for Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, cascading-deletes, change-tracking

Can you track the changes of the records when cascade delete is true?

When I delete a record, I am able to access the record to be deleted in ChangeTracker.Entries() but cannot find the child records which has cascadeDelete = true.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: If the cascade delete is set in the database then you need not to worry as that will be handled by the database itself. The Ef will track changes and delete the base object.

Comment: I need to record every change in my Audit table hence the cascaded deletes. will EF be able to identify 'cascade-delete' entries so I can handle the Audit insertion?

Comment: I dont think so. EF will not be able to identify these.

Comment: hmm. is there a way to intercept this. like when deleting the parent entity, on save changes, check the foreign key relationships of the parent entity, load them and manually delete them before pushed to the DB.